# Optimizing Datetime fields where indexes aren't being used as expected

Tags: mysql, performance, datetime, indexing, database-performance

I have a large, fast-growing log table in an application running with MySQL 5.0.77. I'm trying to find the best way to optimize queries that count instances within the last X days according to message type:

```
CREATE TABLE `counters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kind` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_counters_on_kind` (`kind`),
  KEY `index_counters_on_created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=302 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For this test set, there are 668521 rows in the table. The query I'm trying to optimize is:

```
SELECT kind, COUNT(id) FROM counters WHERE created_at >= ? GROUP BY kind;
```

Right now, that query takes between 3-5 seconds, and is being estimated as follows:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys                    | key                    | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | counters | index | index_counters_on_created_at_idx | index_counters_on_kind | 258     | NULL | 1185531 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------+------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the created_at index removed, it looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key                    | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | counters | index | NULL          | index_counters_on_kind | 258     | NULL | 1185531 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

(Yes, for some reason the row estimate is larger than the number of rows in the table.)

So, apparently, there's no point to that index.

Is there really no better way to do this? I tried the column as a timestamp, and it just ended up slower.

Edit: I discovered that changing the query to use an interval instead of a specific date ends up using the index, cutting down the row estimate to about 20% of the query above:

```
SELECT kind, COUNT(id) FROM counters WHERE created_at >= 
    (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY kind;
```

I'm not entirely sure why that happens, but I'm fairly confident that if I understood it then the problem in general would make a lot more sense.

Comment: I think, that what happened is that when you used a specific date you entered it as a string, and this caused MySQL to do conversion of `created_at` to string and not use the index. Can you try something like `WHERE created_at >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '{specific date}')`?

Comment: No change when using (for example) CONVERT('2011-10-13', DATETIME).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the latest edit on the question, the problem seems to be that the parameter being used in the `WHERE` clause was being interpreted by MySQL as a string rather than as a `datetime` value.  This would explain why the `index_counters_on_created_at` index was not being selected by the optimizer, and instead it would result in a scan to convert the `created_at` values to a string representation and then do the comparison.  I think, this can be prevented by an explicit cast to `datetime` in the `where` clause:

```
where `created_at` >= convert({specific_date}, datetime)
```

My original comments still apply for the optimization part.

The real performance killer here is the `kind` column. Because when doing the `GROUP BY` the database engine first needs to determine all the distinct values in the `kind` column which results in a table or index scan. That's why the estimated rows is bigger than the total number of rows in the table, in one pass it will determine the distinct values in the `kind` column, and in a second pass it will determine which rows meet the `create_at >= ?` condition.
To make matters worse, the `kind` column is a `varchar (255)` which is too big to be efficient, add to that that it uses `utf8` character set and `utf8_unicode_ci` collation, which increment the complexity of the comparisons needed to determine the unique values in that column.

This will perform a lot better if you change the type of the `kind` column to `int`. Because integer comparisons are more efficient and simpler than unicode character comparisons.  It would also help to have a catalog table for the `kind` of messages in which you store the `kind_id` and `description`.  And then do the grouping on a join of the kind catalog table and a subquery of the log table that first filters by date:

```
select k.kind_id, count(*)
from
    kind_catalog k
    inner join (
        select kind_id
        from counters
        where create_at >= ?
    ) c on k.kind_id = c.kind_id
group by k.kind_id
```

This will first filter the `counters` table by `create_at >= ?` and can benefit from the index on that column.  Then it will join that to the `kind_catalog` table and if the SQL optimizer is good it will scan the smaller `kind_catalog` table for doing the grouping, instead of the `counters` table.

Comment: Trying the same query without the kind field involved (and no grouping) yields the same result from EXPLAIN. Kind itself is also indexed (with 99 distinct values).

Comment: What's the query you tried? If you look at the explain output, the key being used is `index_counters_on_kind`.  Also note, that count(*) can be more efficient than count(id).

Comment: The exact query being tried here: select kind, count(*) from counters where created_at >= CONVERT('2011-10-13', DATETIME) group by kind;

Comment: Also tried this one to eliminate kind as the bottleneck: select count(*) from counters where created_at >= CONVERT('2011-10-13', DATETIME);

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a concatenated index?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_counters_created_kind ON counters(created_at, kind);
```

Should go for an Index-Only Scan (mentioning "Using index" in Extras, because COUNT(ID) is NOT NULL anyway).

References:

- [Concatenated index vs. merging multiple indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-merge-performance)
- [Index-Only Scan](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index)

Comment: Just gave this a shot, but it ends up with the same result -- identical estimate from the unindexed version.